# How to make images fade visible when i'm scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

```
    <div id="smiley">
        <div id="star">
            <img src="inc/img/heks.png" class="star">
            <img src="inc/img/impo.png" class="star">
            <img src="inc/img/angst.png" class="star">
        </div>
    </div>

    #smiley{
        margin: 50px auto 80px;
        width: 1132px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    #smiley #star{
        display: none;
        float: left;
        height: 300px;
        width: 1132px;
    }

#smiley #star img.star{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 50px 38px 0px;
}
```

I need have the images to fade visible when i'm scrolling down to them.

i hope you understand the question.

- This website template, does it http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/51771.html

Comment: Are you talking about the image loop at the top that gets changed after some secs continuously in fading animation ??

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It is not so hard to implement with jQuery.

Comment: let me try to make more specific. There are 4 bobles "Hardware" - "networking" - "innovation" - "development" The bobles are going from invisible to visible, then i scroll, i need the same effekt

Comment: Check out my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747983/how-to-animate-this-when-scrolled Also take a look at the website the OP linked to, it might have some animations you'd be interested in and also explains how to do different kinds of animations Like others have said, make sure the element you want to fade in first has `display: none`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chc0rzpv/77/embedded/result/) .. [Source code](http://jsfiddle.net/chc0rzpv/77/)

If you want to show the images only when they become in the window of browser.. without affecting their loading ..

Try this, make the **visibility** of image **hidden**, then using JavaScript add class **fadeIn** to the image when it become in the window of browser ..

**So** .. in your **CSS** :

```
<style>
    .star {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .fadeIn {
        -webkit-animation: animat_show 0.8s;
        animation: animat_show 0.8s;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes animat_show{
        0%{opacity:0}
        100%{opacity:1}
    }
</style>
```

Then load **jQuery** library

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in your **JavaScript**:

```
<script>
    function showImages(el) {
        var windowHeight = jQuery( window ).height();
        $(el).each(function(){
            var thisPos = $(this).offset().top;

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (topOfWindow + windowHeight - 200 > thisPos ) {
                $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
            }
        });
    }

    // if the image in the window of browser when the page is loaded, show that image
    $(document).ready(function(){
            showImages('.star');
    });

    // if the image in the window of browser when scrolling the page, show that image
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            showImages('.star');
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will help you ..

Comment: Nice work buddy.